# How can I move an element from a C++11 container to the back of the container?

Tags: c++, stl

How can I move an element from a C++11 container to the back of the container?

I'm specifically using a list but could use a vector if needed (or probably any container; would be good to get general container solutions).

I have a list of elements. I have a value. I pass this value to each element; one of them will respond. The first one that responds I want to move to the back of the container.

My existing code looks like this:

```
std::list<elements> m_elements
...
bool handle(event e)
{
    for(auto &element : m_elements)
    {
        if(element->handle())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But what I now want to do is move the element that `handle()`s the event to the end of `m_elements`. For a bit of context, I'm working on a GUI system of windows. So whichever window happens to capture the mouse needs to jump to the top when being drawn; windows in `m_elements` are being drawn one by one (so the last element is on top).

It might be worth noting that elements are `std::shared_ptr`s.

### **EDIT**

In case anyone comes across this question and answer for a similar situation.

I actually needed to iterate backwards through my container to process input because the last element is drawn last, i.e. it is on top, so it should be the first element that should try to intercept input.

This was simple to do. However, splicing a reverse iterator to the end of your container is a bit trickier. `std::reverse_iterator.base()` returns you the NEXT iterator if the iterator was a forward iterator, so you need to `std::advance` the iterator by `-1` in order to successfully move the actual element that "intercepted".

```
for(auto itr = m_elements.rbegin(); itr != m_elements.rend(); ++itr)
{
    if((*itr)->handle(e))
    {
        auto itr2 = itr.base();
        std::advance(itr2,-1);
        m_elements.splice(m_elements.end(), m_elements, itr2);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps the next poor soul.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: why not just swap them?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [std::partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)

Comment: Because partition and swap are not order-preserving for the other elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove the element and add it to the end (effectively shifting everything else down) then  you can do this by using the `std::list::splice` method, which will relink the node at a new location without requiring any nodes to be created or destroyed.  All it will do is tweak the node pointers on existing nodes to reflect the change you want.

```
for (auto i = m_elements.begin(); i != m_elements.end(); ++i) {
    if ((*i)->handle()) {
        // Move this node to the back.
        m_elements.splice(m_elements.end(), m_elements, i);

        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

There are more general solutions that will apply to any container (including `std::list`) but they may be sub-optimal compared to a technique for that particular container.

Comment: Wouldn't it invalidate the collection, and make for-loop to fail?

Comment: @Ajay After `m_elements.erase(i)` the `i` iterator is indeed invalid, but it doesn't matter because we return immediately afterwards. If we needed to continue iterating through the array then we would have to use the `i = m_elements.erase(i)` idiom and move `++i` into an `else` block, but since we are not there is no concern.

Comment: @Ajay And note my edit -- `std::list::splice` exists for exactly this reason, and saves a node construction, `std::shared_ptr` move-construction, and node destruction by adjusting some internal pointers.